# Anaconda: Upload to the global channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, python-packaging

I use pip since a while, but I need now to use Anaconda because it supports `h5py` on Windows without having to compile it.

I uploaded my first package to Anaconda.org (using [this](https://conda.io/docs/build_tutorials/pkgs2.html) tutorial), and everything went smoothly. But... I noticed that i have to run this command to install:

```
conda install mypackage -c myusername
```

While I notice that other packages (like PyQt and h5py) can be installed with:

```
conda install h5py
```

So apparently there's something special to be done to gain access to the "global channel". I couldn't find any information about that whatsoever. How can I upload my package to the global channel?

Answer (score 1):

All packages in conda are installed from channels. By default, the `defaults` channel is added to the configuration file. So, you just need to add your channel to be automatically searched in the configuration file.

```
conda config --add channels myusername
```

will ensure that your channel is searched *before* the existing channels, while

```
conda config --append channels myusername
```

will ensure that your channel is searched after any existing channels.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Though this sounds like adding configuration locally. Meaning: If I go to another computer, I won't be able to do `conda install mysoftware`, unless I redo this config. So I guess my question is: How did the guys of `h5py` get it to work on my computer without ever having to get me to add the config you mentioned?

Comment: The `defaults` channel is maintained by Continuum Analytics, the creators/maintainers of conda. So you'll have to get in touch with them to get your package added to the `defaults`... Otherwise, you'll have to package `conda`/Python yourself and make a new distribution :-)

Comment: Is there like a standard contact form or request to be made?

Comment: Not so far as I know. You may be able to raise the issue at https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues or just send Continuum IO an email directly.

Comment: I did actually raise an issue actually in another repos on github. Waiting for their response.